# Alternate solution for Row_Number?

Tags: sql, vertica

I have a table which contains too much data (10 cr). For Paging purpose i have used 
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Order by id), but its getting very slow in select. So please give any alternate soluion? (Using verica)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a temp table with an identity column. Good read

[How to dynamically number rows in a SELECT Transact-SQL statement](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/186133/en-us)

Comment: Thanks , Its ok in sql .But vertica its not possible in creating temp table with identity